# Write Performance of elasticsearch 2.2.0

Tags: elasticsearch

I was using Elasticsearch 1.7 and an indexation operation was taking between 10ms and 100ms.

Using the exact same mapping on Elasticsearch 2.2, the indexation time is between 2s and 5s!

I use multi-threading system to send the HTTP requests (50 simulatenous requests)

Does anyone has an explanation?

**Edit**
The mapping : https://github.com/Socrate93/Sample/blob/master/mapping.json
I'm trying to insert Locations.

Comment: Maybe we can help if you show us the mapping you're using. Otherwise this will be just guess work.

Comment: @Val I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

A major difference between 1.7 and 2 is `doc_values` is enabled by default in 2.x versions. The difference is probably the creation time of the data structures of doc values at index time. 
If you are sure that you do not need sorting or aggregation on some of your fields you can disable the doc_values on them.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I disabled doc_values, but execution time didn't change